# wpf 3D animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d, xna

Can I use WPF to import a 3D character and manually animate it like the skinned model 
in XNA?

Comment: Yes.  But I suspect you'd like an example, which is why I'm not answering with this.

Comment: so what about it's performance vs xna animation ?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. There is no standard library in WPF which will support this.

The long answer is Yes; if you write all of the underlying code yourself.

Comment: I rather suspect the answer for the OP is no.